# progressDialog animations pauses on large setText()

Tags: android, multithreading, android-edittext

I'm trying to set a large text in a EditText, the operation can take over 30 seconds so I use a ProgressDialog. It shows up, but there's no animation, and then disappears when the operation is done. Here's my simplified code:

```
class FileOpener extends AsyncTask<File, Integer, String> {

    private ProgressDialog progress;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress = new ProgressDialog(context);
        ...
        progress.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected StringBuilder doInBackground(File... files) {
        return readFile();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String content) {
        EditText editText = ...
        editText.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                editText.setText(content);
                progress.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

What can I do to animate the progress dialog while setting text?

I also tried using this in `onPostExecute`, same thing, dialog is there but no animation...

```
EditText editText = ...
new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        editor.setText(content);
        progress.dismiss();
    }
}.start();
```

---

**EDIT** - This is NOT a question on my EditText speed, which is awful as I understood. This question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41885344/improve-edittext-performance-with-large-text?noredirect=1#comment70953334_41885344). No matter how I improve the speed, setting the text will ALWAYS take a few seconds with big files, it doesn't even with top editing apps. What this question is really about is how to keep the loading dialog animation, because currently, it doesn't animate while setting the text in the EditText. I know nothing nothing can be changed on the UI if not in UI thread, then how can I update/animate the loading? If this is impossible or simply too complicated or hacky, then how can I show a loading animation of any sort while setting the text.

Comment: There is a function called `onProgressUpdate()`, in AsyncTask. Then in your `readFile()`, call `publishProgress(yourValue)`.

Comment: Actually what's taking most time is setting the text. Reading the file can take 1 sec while setting the text can take 30 sec. And I can't really call this function inside setText...

Comment: Oh i see, you can try to `setText` directly after `readFile()`, in `runOnUiThread()`, and just dismiss your dialog in the `PostExecute()`. To call `runOnUiThread()`, you need a Activity.

Comment: How can setting a `String` on an `EditText` take more than 1ms ?

Comment: @RaphaelTeyssandier No, when doing this the dialog gets dismissed before the text is set.

Comment: just an assumption, but if your edittext is already on the ui, settext will block the UIThread (on which the animation runs) as well. 30 seconds to display your text sounds like an issue, you'll have to work around.

Comment: @ChristianR. That's why I want to run the progress dialog in another thread. Or any solution to keep the dialog loading while setting text. 30 sec durations are achieved with files over 500KB, I guess it's normal for such a size.

Comment: FYI 500kb is nothing. It's 2017. Downloading 500kb and processing it should take about as long as blinking your eye

Comment: setText, like any other operation on UI thread, should never take 30s, and if you are sure that is really taking that much time (and it shouldn't be possible because it's 29x more than reading the actual content from file), something is very very wrong

Comment: I posted a question about the EditText performance [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41885344/improve-edittext-performance-with-large-text).

Comment: You can't do any UI operation in some other Worker thread, you has to do it in your main UIThread.Didn't get what you want to achieve exactly.

Comment: can you provide a sample file of text herE?

Comment: Please read my edit... As I said, even if that's not relevant to the question at all, [here's your sample](http://www.exploratorium.edu/pi/pi_archive/Pi10-6.html). That's 1MB

Comment: @NicolasMaltais . see my answer.  I tested it with 500kb of dummy text. I hope it helps you.

Comment: post your code you use to set the text (that takes 30 seconds). If your progress dialog isn't animating, then it sounds to me like you are blocking the main (UI) thread and you are obviously setting the text on the main (UI) thread.

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to minimize the animation pausing/stopping
by creating an EditText and setting its text in your `doInBackground` and adding it to view in your `onPostExecute` (the ui thread). Here is an example using an Activity and variation of the task you already have with some code comments:

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * dummy edit text (or the old one if doing an update)
     */
    private EditText dummyEditTextForShow;
    /**
     * that dummy's parent
     */
    private ViewGroup viewGroupToAddEditTextTo;
    /**
     * that dummy's position in it's parent
     */
    int indexOfDummy;
    /**
     * your progress dialog
     */
    private ProgressDialog progress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // create the things
        progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dummyEditTextForShow = new EditText(this);
        // show the place holder
        setContentView(dummyEditTextForShow);
        // get its parent and index in parent
        viewGroupToAddEditTextTo = (ViewGroup) dummyEditTextForShow.getParent();
        indexOfDummy = viewGroupToAddEditTextTo.indexOfChild(dummyEditTextForShow);
        new FileOpener().execute();
    }

    class FileOpener extends AsyncTask<File, Integer, EditText> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progress.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected EditText doInBackground(File... files) {
            EditText newEditText = new EditText(Activity.this);
            newEditText.setText(readFile());
            return newEditText;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(EditText editText) {
            //get rid of old for the new
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams oldLayoutParams = dummyEditTextForShow.getLayoutParams();
            viewGroupToAddEditTextTo.removeView(dummyEditTextForShow);
            viewGroupToAddEditTextTo.addView(editText, indexOfDummy, oldLayoutParams));
            progress.hide();
            dummyEditTextForShow = editText
        }
    }
}
```

I tested the above using a http://www.webpagefx.com/tools/lorem-ipsum-generator/loremipsum/paragraphs
Paragraphs: 100 
Size: 46929 bytes

Set to one string value `fiftykb` and then created another String `all` very lazily and set it to the new edit text (instead of your `readFile()`):

```
String all = fiftykb + fiftykb + fiftykb + fiftykb + fiftykb + fiftykb + fiftykb + fiftykb + fiftykb + fiftykb;
newEditText.setText(all)
```

Results were that the animation never stops, but there is a brief moment (< 1 sec) the edit text is blank and then shows all the text and is editable.

HTHs!

Comment: test was on a kindle fire hd 8

Comment: Didn't try it yet, but didn't setting text in doInBackground block the animation?

Comment: >but didn't setting text in doInBackground block the animation?  in my above example, No.

Comment: You are updating the edittext in doInBackground which runs on background thread

Comment: @NicolasMaltais how about that bounty!

Comment: @NicolasMaltais, Please accept this correct answer. You should accept correct answers and give your promised due in time (bounty) when people give enough of their time to solve your problem and help you.

Comment: Yea sorry I was waiting to test it but I guess it works so here you go :)

Comment: @petey Okay I just tried it and I get _Method setText must be called from the UI thread, currently inferred thread is worker_ on `editText.setText(text)`, and `new EditText(context)`. Solution would be use `runOnUIThread` which defeats the purpose of this answer.

Comment: if the EditText is already added to the screen that will happen,  thats why the creation of the edittext along with the setText, is done in the background . Then it is added to to the screen on the ui thread via onPostExecute.

Comment: perhaps you are getting a lint error,  in that case you may need to add the `@SuppressWarnings("WrongThread")` above the `doInBackground` declaration to defeat the lint check.

Comment: @petey Okay I just did everything you suggested: sometimes the progress dialog doesn't even show up, and when it does, the loading is not animated, it blocks. Any idea why?