# Setting a very large text into an EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am making an app which is reading the text file and display content into EditText, but I am facing one issue is that when the file is too large (which is more than 1mb) than setting text into EditText takes some time and app get stuck.

If anyone knows that is there any other option to display text into EditText then please help me. I got stuck over here

```
edittext.setText(text);//got stuck here
```

this `readFile()` is inside `AsyncTask` and `setText()` is inside `onPostExecute()`

```
public String readFile(String fileName) {
    StringBuilder builder = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("File not found");
        }


        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
            builder.append("\n");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return builder != null ? builder.toString() : "";
}
```

**Edit**

Now I am not using `BufferedReader` to read a file. I am reading a file using `c` code

Comment: check this: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/NoteEditor.htm

Comment: I checked this, but this is not useful for me, Thanks

Comment: what is your `text` look like?

Comment: [May be relevant - link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801232/edittext-performance-understanding-gpu-process-time-on-profile-gpu-rendering). I had a similar issue writing a text editing application once.

Comment: the `text` is a `string` which is read from `.txt` file

Comment: This answer is a very interesting solution to the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41904130/1219389

Essentially, you create your `EditText` on a background thread and set the text there, but don't add it to your layout until `onPostExecute`.

Comment: @PPartisan Wouldn't this still cause a delay? I might be wrong but the only difference I forsee is the visibility of the EditText. The delay would still be there.

Comment: I expect the delay would still be there, but it wouldn't block the UI thread so you could show some kind of feedback at least, like a loading dialog

Comment: @PPartisan, I have changed the reading file code. Now I am reading file form `c`, so the reading file is faster than `BufferedReader` which is less than 1 sec, so now the delay is while set text into `EditText`

Comment: Yes, I understand, and I never found a good solution to that. Calling `setText()` on an `EditText` that is created in the background at least means you can show some kind of visual feedback that the text is being loaded - otherwise any loading feedback you show will be blocked.

Comment: @PPartisan, how can I show any loader over there, because I will not get any event that all text is set in the `EditText`, is there any callback in which we can get such event?

Comment: No, you set the text in `doInBackground()`, which blocks that thread. When it is complete your `AsyncTask` will call `onPostExectue`. Look at the answer I linked - it will be much faster than trying to explain it to you.

Comment: okay, let me implement like that

Comment: @PPartisan an answer you suggested me will not work because we can not access any of widget on the inferred thread

Comment: Make sure you follow the answer carefully. Attempting to call `setText()` from a background thread will cause an error _unless_ that view is newly created and hasn't been attached the layout yet.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is expected. Intuitively, it would take more time to read larger files. There are a couple of options you can use to manage this situation.

#### Scenario one:

Do you have access to the file long before you have to perform `edittext.setText(...)`?

If yes, you can use a service to get the text you need to display long before hand and save it to a more accessible storage (i.e SharedPreferences). Displaying the text after this would result to zero delay.

#### Scenario two:

If scenario one is not fulfilled...

There is actually nothing wrong with a delay. What matters is how you present the delay to your user. You can make use of a progressBar or a loading animation to abstract this delay.